# I am getting an error when I try to add migration in ASP.NET Core application which I connected with MySQL server of xamp

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

This is the error I get:

> Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'Method not found: 'Void CoreTypeMappingParameters..ctor(System.Type, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueConversion.ValueConverter, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ValueComparer, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ValueComparer, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ValueComparer, System.Func`3<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IProperty,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IEntityType,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ValueGeneration.ValueGenerator>)'.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

Connection

```
"dbcs": "Server=localhost;Port=3307;Database=asp1;user=root;password=;" //this is located in json file
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("dbcs");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<StudentDbContext>(item =>
{
    item.UseMySql(connectionString,ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString));
});
var app = builder.Build();
```

`DbContext`:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace WebApplication2.Models
{
    public class StudentDbContext:DbContext
    {
        public StudentDbContext(DbContextOptions op) : base(op)
        {    
        }

        public DbSet<StudentModel> Students { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Model class:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace WebApplication2.Models
{
    public class StudentModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Fill the name")]
        [Column("Student Name", TypeName="varchar(20)")]
        public string Name { get; set; }   
        public int Age { get; set; }

        public string Gender { get; set; }
    }
}
```

How can I solve this error? This is for .NET 8 and EF Core 8

Comment: I usually find migration fails due to the connection string.  DBCS is an Oracle database, not mySQL.  Check Connection string for proper string : https://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: applied..didn't work

Comment: Where is the database being created?  You do not have permission to write the new database. The location of the database is in the connection string.  The database may already exist so you cannot overwrite the database with a new database.

Comment: tried database with different name that are not present in xamp server..but didn't work

Comment: Did you setup database using these instructions?  https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~up3f/cs4750/supplement/DB-setup-xampp.html

Comment: Do you have latest version? https://www.apachefriends.org/blog/new_xampp_20231119.html

Comment: yes..i have..are this is a problem of xamp?

Comment: See following : https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=279579&sid=a23b085caacc9d243098452124cd8ab9#p279655

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced the error with following package version
[image]
[image]

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore(8.0.0)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design(8.0.0)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools(8.0.0)
Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql(7.0.0)
```

The issue disappeared with follwing package version:
[image]
[image]

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore(7.0.14)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design(7.0.14)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools(7.0.14)
Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql(7.0.0)
```

Since `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.Mysql` lasted support version is 7.0.0, it is better keep all the efcore related packages to version 7.X.

Comment: Images are not showing for some reason

Comment: @SAFIQULISLAMUZZAL203-15-144 I updated my answer with text written packages version, you could try it.